# How can I set 'Minimum Order Amount' for each currency in Magento

Tags: currency, multicurrency

I have different currencies in Magento store and I want to display separate Minimum Order value message in respective currency

Eg: I have Base currency as dollar. In `System > Sales` I have set minimum Order Amount 1000 and display message as T`HE MINIMUM VALUE ALLOWED FOR PURCHASE IS $ 1000`

Now in Display `Currency INR option` I want the minimum order amount to be 64000 and Display Message `THE MINIMUM VALUE ALLOWED FOR PURCHASE IS ₹ 64000`

Can someone guide on this?

Answer (score 1):

Magento is validate this Minimum Order value at

`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`  class on function  `validateMinimumAmount()`

and

`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` class on function  `validateMinimumAmount()`

- For your requirement you `need override those two classes`
- Create Different different minimum price using create new option to
  system.xml
  On this custom setting you need change the logic.